# prevent css animation from going through the color palatte when changing between colors

Tags: css

```css
#blinking {
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes example {
    0%   { background-color: black; }
    50%  { background-color: white; color: black; }
    100% { background-color: black; }
}
```

```html
<h2 id='completed'>Bot submitte<strong id='blinking'>d</strong> </h2>
```

(I have my code attached as a snippet) So basically im trying to make a caret blinking animation, as u can tell when the black background fades in, it fades in, and i dont want that, i want it to come in in an instant and go away in an instant

Answer (score 1):

You can use `animation-timing-function: steps` which you can read more at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function

Comment: oo i used step-start and it works thanks